# Memory leak in getImageData and passing to worker

Tags: javascript

In my main page it has a timer(1 second) to pass data to worker. The code is attached, the worker does nothing.

The memory in task manager keeps increasing very fast, how to avoid the memory leak?

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
let video = this.runtime.ioDevices.video.provider.video;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
let canvas_data = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, 640, 480).data
window.myWorker.postMessage({ type: "test", file: file, data: canvas_data });
```

Comment: What's the worker doing with data?

Comment: @Keith Nothing. I removed all the code only one  onmessage() is left. Looks like a bug or by design? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68190

Comment: Crikey!, that bug report is from 2010.  If you clone the buffer does it seem to help.  eg.  `const clone = new Uint32Array(imageData.length); clone.set(imageData);`, and use that?  The only other thing I would say, inside both the worker & the main are you allowing the GC to breath..?